# ошибка при установке laravel с помощью composer

Tags: laravel, composer

```
  $ composer create-project laravel/laravel neew


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2013%249ce136be8db9815d09f80232d0
  c0c1644e2f022d1317af675edaede92324d060.json" file could not be downloaded:
  send of 230 bytes failed with errno=10054 ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒
  ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒.

  failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]


User@home-pc MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/laravel
$ composer global require laravel/install
Changed current directory to C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Composer


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2013%249ce136be8db9815d09f80232d0
  c0c1644e2f022d1317af675edaede92324d060.json" file could not be downloaded:
  send of 230 bytes failed with errno=10054 ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒
  ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒.

  failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`, `composer global require laravel/installer`.

Comment: Вроде [было](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324779/install-laravel-with-composer)

Comment: убедитесь, что у вас в php подключено расширение `openssl`

Comment: @StanislavHmelevsky спасибо большое! получилось

Comment: @saltonik Пожалуйста!)